# Issue with focus element in GotFocus/Activated event

Tags: winforms, compact-framework, onfocus

There is form with text element that should receive focus every time form shown.

In .NET CF Form has no OnShow(n) event

I try to use workaround:

```
MyForm_GotFocus() // or MyForm_Activated
{
   txtTextControl.Text = string.Empty;
   txtTextControl.Focus()
}

txtTextControl_GotFocus()
{
    txtTextControl.SelectAll()
}
```

Code for getting form instance:

```
public static MyForm GetForm
{
    get
    {    
       if (s_inst == null || s_inst.IsDisposed)
       {
         s_inst = new MyForm();
       }
    return s_inst; 
    }
}

public static void ShowForm()
{
   var frm = GetForm;
   frm.Show();
}
```

1) First time ShowForm (Form instance has been created): txtTextControl emptied and got focus, txtTextControl_GotFocus event raised

2) Second time ShowForm : OK too

3) Third time ShowForm : txtTextControl emptied, but **does not get focus**

Is there bug or feature? Is there workaround? Show I rewrite ShowForm? Is OpenNETCF.IOC.UI is better solution (50 forms in project)?

Comment: Try overriding OnActivated and then focusing your textbox (or whatever you want to do). There's no way for me to test this right now, so I won't post it as an answer because I do not know for sure that it will work. If it works, comment, and I'll re-post as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had that same question once.

Set the TabIndex for the control to 0.